# I am trying to do Element Control, Redirection and Form Submission Processing with WIX Code but I am unable to find a suitable method

Tags: javascript, html, velo

I'm kind of a beginner to WIX Code. I have this site which I have made i.e www.rat-store.com. I am facing three problems which I know might get solved with some code but I don't know how to do it. Here are the problems:

1. In manual payment, I need to accept some form input from the user on a page and only if the user agrees to the terms and enters the correct date should the submit button get activated following which an otherwise collapsed image should also reveal (it's the QR code to make payment; Image 1) (www.rat-store.com/manual-pay-rat)

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DTtw.png)

2. I'm trying to link a repeater background to a page but it's not working. I have to create a button inside the repeater to do this. Any workarounds? I know an image will work but the thing is that the motive is to create a kind of a list which will keep on incrementing in the future and I can't just keep on drag-dropping images, text and then group them up and link. (Image 2) (www.rat-store.com/shop-by-events)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxYtV.png)

3. Since WIX Stores doesn't have an inbuilt cancellation feature I built a form to substitute for the same but I want that no two same order cancellations are submitted i.e. a customer can only submit his/her cancellation request for a particular order number once. The next time s/he tries to do that it should show that the request already exists. (Image 3 and Image 4) (www.rat-store.com/cancel-orders)

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXvGE.png)
[Image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CM4kI.png)

Some help with the code and approach would really be great. I'm almost finished with my site; Only these last few things bother me. I'm attaching a screenshot of each page, serially w.r.t the question number. P.S: The order number is the number generated for each order by the Wix store app itself. I have nothing to do with that. The customer needs to enter his/her number and if that is valid we will process the request. Apologies for the length of the post.

Comment: Deleting the WiX tag because it isn't the wix that you think it is.

Comment: Alright. @PhilDW